# Caching smarty view render

Tags: smarty, yii

I'm working with Yii framework and using smarty view render. I have to working with simpleXML_load_file to load simpleXML element and it's can not be cache using data caching with memcache provided by Yii. So I think may be using cache of smarty instead of caching data. Anyone here had caching smarty page in Yii framework give me some advises, thank a lot!

Comment: Now I can cached using memcache with Yii but I still wonder how to cache html page like smarty in Yii, anyone here give me a hand for this!! tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I see no reason data cache will not work with SimpleXML element.
2. You can try using [full page cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.page).
3. You can define your own Smarty tags for [fragment cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.fragment).